# Contraction-like mapping without fixed point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $\xi:\;X\to X$ satisfies:

$$d(x,y)<n+1\Rightarrow d(\xi(x),\xi(y))<n$$
$$d(x,y)<1/n\Rightarrow d(\xi(x),\xi(y))<1/(n+1)$$
for all $n= 1,2,\dots$, does $\xi$ necessarily have a fixed point?

I am not sure what to do with this question; I would guess the answer is no, but I am having trouble constructing a counter-example. If someone could offer a hint I would be thankful.

Comment: Have you tried mimicking the existence proof for the case when $\xi$ is a contraction? Does it work? If not, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let the metric space be $\mathbb{N}$ with this metric: $$d(m,n)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac1{m\wedge n}=\frac1m\vee\frac1n&m\ne n,\\0&m=n\end{cases}$$ (where $\wedge$ stands for minimum and $\vee$ for maximum). Now let $\xi\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be given by $\xi(n)=n+1$.

Comment: (Thanks to @AsalBeagDubh for pointing out a silly mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $E_n$ as follows:
$$
  E_n  = \begin{cases}
  \{(x,y): n+1\leq d(x,y)<n+2\}, & n\geq0
\\
  \{(x,y): \frac{1}{|n|+1}\leq d(x,y)<\frac1{|n|}\}, & n\leq-1
\end{cases}
$$
then if $(x,y)\in E_n$ then $(\xi(x),\xi(y))\in E_{n-1}$ and in particular $\lim_n d(\xi^n(x),\xi^n(y)) = 0$ for all $x,y\in X$. From that, I guess you can proceed yourself.

Comment: Don't know about the OP, but I can't use your answer to get to a full solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

Let $\xi ^n = \xi^{n-1}\circ\xi\ $ where $\xi^1 = \xi$.

Let $x_0 = x\in X$, and $x_n = \xi(x_{n-1})$, i.e. $x_n = \xi^n(x)$.

What can you say about $d(x_n, x_{n-1})$ as $n$ aproaches infinity?

Note that since $X$ is a complete metric space, then $\tilde{x}:=\left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \right)\in X$.

**Bonus:**

Now you can also prove that the fixed point is unique:

Assume that there are at least two fixed points $\tilde{x}$ and $\tilde{y}$.

What can you say about $d(\xi(\tilde{x}),\xi(\tilde{y}))$ in terms of $d(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$?

Comment: To my understanding, there isn't much that can be said. The fact that $d(x_n,x_{n-1})\to0$ does not imply this sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Since when did $d(x_n,x_{n-1})\to0$ imply the convergence of $(x_n)$? That is not quite the Cauchy criterion, after all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen that is true, but note that $d(x_n, x_{n-1})$ is bounded by a sequence that DOES follow the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: Consider $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}$. Does it converge?